# utf-8 encoding problem (I am using BeautifulSoup to parse pandas documentation)

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to parse a site with pandas documentation (I do some statistical calculations on words). For this I use simple code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, fromEncoding = 'utf8')
p_tags = soup.find_all('p')
page_text = []
for p_tag in p_tags:
  page_text.append(p_tag.text)
page_text
```

> ['The User Guide covers all of pandas by topic area. Each of the subsections\nintroduces a topic (such as â\x80\x9cworking with missing dataâ\x80\x9d), and discusses how\npandas approaches the problem, with many examples throughout.',
> 'Users brand-new to pandas should start with 10 minutes to pandas.',
> 'For a high level summary of the pandas fundamentals, see Intro to data structures and Essential basic functionality.',
> 'Further information on any specific method can be obtained in the\nAPI reference.',
> '\n          © Copyright 2008-2021, the pandas development team.\n        Created using Sphinx 3.5.1.\n']

I have a problem with the encoding ("'" - on the pandas site => â \ x80 \ x9c - after parsing). Please tell me how I can fix this. Parameter fromEncoding = 'utf8' added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a parser, for example, `lxml` and `.content` not `.text`. Also, you don't need `fromEncoding`.

See this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html')
p_tags = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml").find_all('p')
page_text = []
for p_tag in p_tags:
    page_text.append(p_tag.text)
print(page_text)
```

Output:

> The User Guide covers all of pandas by topic area. Each of the
> subsections introduces a topic (such as “working with missing data”),
> and discusses how pandas approaches the problem, with many examples
> throughout. Users brand-new to pandas should start with 10 minutes to
> pandas. For a high level summary of the pandas fundamentals, see Intro
> to data structures and Essential basic functionality. Further
> information on any specific method can be obtained in the API
> reference.